# Weird import behavior on legacy Java project

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6, legacy

Currently working on an old project (Java 6) using NetBeans 8.1, and I am having issues with imports.

Say I have packages A and B. Package A has a file with some imports, and B has another file with other imports. I added a new Java class in package B, and all the imports are not working, with the error being `The import [class] cannot be resolved`. But then I move the same Java class to package A and all imports are working. If I were to then reference this class in package A, from package B, it will give me the same error for that class.

Funnily enough, this only happens when I do a clean and build, and the IDE does not show any error lines, and the error is shown in the console in black and white rather than red.

I have also tried to create a new package within package A and put the file there, and it actually works. So I am assuming that there is a setting that is not letting the imports work. And yes, the imports that I am using, are compatible with Java 6. Here is a sample of some imports being used:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Updating the system is sadly not possible, as it is a legacy system that has to stay up. Also please note, that this is the first time that this project ever had new files added to it, so it might be that it's a hard coded configuration from netbeans or something else (gwt?) that might be creating this issue.

Are there any other tests that I can do to see where the problem might be? And maybe if this was a common issue back then?

Comment: This is an error thrown by the IDE, but everything compiles fine?

Comment: It's difficult to guess from what you've shown.  I worked with that version of Java extensively and there wasn't anything different when it came to imports.  Can you share a bit of code that has the issue?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli It compiles successfully, but it doesn't reflect the actual changes in the build. So it stays with an old build.

Comment: @stdunbar The code is literally just that sadly. A new, empty file, and the imports I mentioned, that's it. The IDE even autocompletes it for me but does not actually register it when building

Comment: I’m still not understanding the problem. So far I believe you’re saying that when you add a class to Package A the IDE shows you a checked exception, but that it compiles successfully. However, when you add a new class in Package A even though it compiles ( despite the IDE showing the checked exception ) the class file is not in the resulting war/jar file?  Is this a correct description of the problem?

Comment: Also, do you see any of the following files in the root of your projects workspace: nb-actions.xml, nb-configuration.xml, catalog.xml?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli That is basically the problem yes. Which then ends up not being able to deploy the new code cause it does not compile it with the new updated features.
With regards to the files, I can only see the catalog.xml. The other files dont exist within the entire project

Comment: Can you update your question to include what is in catalog.xml?  Also, can you unzip your war/jar file and take a screenshot of the directory ( path ) that is missing the new class?  I just basically want verification that the class is actually missing from the new war/jar and the best way to check that is to unzip the compressed "binary", navigate to the directory ( the correlates with the package path ).  I'm 99% sure this is a netbeans issue, im just trying to get some more info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238834/discussion-between-chris-maggiulli-and-nathaniel-cutajar).

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to fix the issue. Basically it was a NetBeans issue. I deleted the project from NetBeans, and reopened it again, imported it's required dependencies, and it compiled successfully without the errors mentioned.

I then continued testing by using the imports that were 'bad' on other classes that did not for some reason like the new imports, and they also worked fine.

So basically the solution seemed to be a longer approach to 'turn it off and then back on'